# How do I find the type of an input in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, input, input-type-range

Sorry I'm a beginner and I can't find how to get the **input** type in angular.
This is the piece of code i have written:

```
passwordVisibilityToggle() {

var x = document.getElementById("password");
var passwordEye = document.getElementById("password-eye");

if (x.type === 'password') {
  x.type = "text";
  passwordEye?.classList.remove("off");
  passwordEye?.classList.add("on");
 } else {
   x.type = "password";
   passwordEye?.classList.remove("on");
  passwordEye?.classList.add("off");
 }
```

}

When I use typeof(x) it gives me this:
This condition will always return 'false' since the types '"string" | "number" | "bigint" | "boolean" | "symbol" | "undefined" | "object" | "function"' and '"password"' have no overlap.ts(2367)
Any advice would be appreciated

Comment: You need to add more code. This is a bit unreadable.

Comment: You need to show more code. For instance, what is x? Also, do you mean get the type of element, like `<input type='password' />`?

Comment: sorry guys, i added the full function i'm using i hope it's more readable now. 
also, yes i do mean the type of the input element (not the type of variable like int, bool, string, ...)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a template reference on the input like this

```
<input #someInput ...
```

Then reference the input in the TypeScript file with the [`@ViewChild`](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) annotation:

```
@ViewChild('someInput') input: ElementRef;
```

Then you'll be able to check the type of the input anywhere in the code with this:

```
(this.input.nativeElement as HTMLInputElement).type === 'password';
```

If your question is about querying all of the inputs then add the same template reference on all of them, then use:

```
@ViewChildren('someInput') inputs!: QueryList<ElementRef>
```

Comment: I tried this but it unfortunately didn't work for me.
This is the code I write with the help you gave:

In HTML :
`code` <input #passwordInput type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" />
            <div id="password-eye" class="off"></div> `code`

And for typescript I'll post it in the next comment cuz it's too long

Comment: In typescript:
`code` @ViewChild('passwordInput') input: ElementRef;
  passwordVisibilityToggle() {
    var passwordEye = document.getElementById("password-eye");
    if ((this.input.nativeElement as HTMLInputElement).type === 'password')
    {
      (this.input.nativeElement as HTMLInputElement).type = "text";
      passwordEye?.classList.remove("off");
      passwordEye?.classList.add("on");
     } else {
      (this.input.nativeElement as HTMLInputElement).type = "password";
       passwordEye?.classList.remove("on");
      passwordEye?.classList.add("off");
     }
  } `code`

Comment: Can you edit your answer, add your attempt and the error you have?

Answer (score 0):

The method you used is that of vanilla js

In angular you should use the forms module reactive forms will carter for this with little effort
To read on angular forms module click [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview&ved=2ahUKEwjRzKC68rPwAhUirXEKHQ9DCfIQFjADegQIBhAC&usg=AOvVaw0OoRextv3B-BgoeksZsCMT)